# How to stop this flickering issue ,which occurs when the UI element is moved using touch?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, events, touch

I have a problem when I try to move the textblock using touch there is a flickering issue which does not occur when I do the same using mouse interaction. can someone help me here?

**How to Stop this flickering issue?**

```
  public partial class MainWindow: Window
  {
    Canvas can = new Canvas() { Background=Brushes.White};
    Grid grid = new Grid() { Height=150,Width=100,Background=Brushes.Yellow};
    TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock() { Text = "TextBlock Text" ,FontWeight=FontWeights.Bold };
    Point point = new Point();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        grid.Children.Add(textBlock);
        can.Children.Add(grid);
        Canvas.SetLeft(grid, 0);
        Canvas.SetTop(grid, 0);
        textBlock.PreviewMouseDown += TextBlock_PreviewMouseDown;
        textBlock.PreviewTouchDown += TextBlock_PreviewTouchDown;
        can.PreviewMouseMove += Can_PreviewMouseMove;
        can.PreviewTouchMove += Can_PreviewTouchMove;
        m_grid.Children.Add(can);

    }

    private void TextBlock_PreviewTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        point = e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position;

    }

    private void TextBlock_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

            point = e.GetPosition(this);
    }

    private void Can_PreviewTouchMove(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource is TextBlock )
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(grid, e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position.X - point.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(grid, e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position.Y - point.Y);
        }
    }


    private void Can_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.OriginalSource is TextBlock && e.LeftButton==MouseButtonState.Pressed&&e.StylusDevice==null)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(grid, e.GetPosition(this).X - point.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(grid, e.GetPosition(this).Y - point.Y);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I tested your code, and I do not experience any flickering issues.

Comment: Can you please check it again???
Try doing this,
* Run the sample,
*Now move the textblock,using mouse
*Now move it using touch see the difference 
*You can able to see the minor shaking of textblock during the movement using touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce the flickering you're encountering, but I think it may be due to your implementation of drag/touch and drop.

The first problem I encountered with the code you posted was in the `PreviewTouchDown` and `PreviewMouseDown` event handlers. The code was setting the `point` to be relative to `this` - the `Window` - which when you first drag is okay, but after that any other drag attempt will immediately move the item up to the top/left corner.

To fix this, I edited the event handlers to set `point` to be relative to the `grid` so that the drag calculations would be correct on subsequent drags.

The second problem is that you are not capturing the mouse or touch device when dragging, which when dragging near the edge of the `grid` will cause the drag to stop. Capturing the mouse or touch will also make the drag much smoother.

To fix this, I added mouse and touch capture to the `PreviewTouchDown` and `PreviewMouseDown` event handlers, and added `TouchUp` and `MouseUp` event handlers that release the capture.

Here's the updated code in full:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Canvas can = new Canvas() { Background = Brushes.White };
    private Grid grid = new Grid() { Height = 150, Width = 100, Background = Brushes.Yellow };
    private TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock() { Text = "TextBlock Text", FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold };
    private Point point = new Point();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        grid.Children.Add(textBlock);
        can.Children.Add(grid);
        Canvas.SetLeft(grid, 0);
        Canvas.SetTop(grid, 0);
        textBlock.PreviewMouseDown += TextBlock_PreviewMouseDown;
        textBlock.PreviewTouchDown += TextBlock_PreviewTouchDown;
        textBlock.MouseUp += TextBlock_MouseUp;
        textBlock.TouchUp += TextBlock_TouchUp;
        can.PreviewMouseMove += Can_PreviewMouseMove;
        can.PreviewTouchMove += Can_PreviewTouchMove;
        RootGrid.Children.Add(can);
    }

    private void TextBlock_PreviewTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        point = e.GetTouchPoint(grid).Position;
        e.TouchDevice.Capture(textBlock);
    }

    private void TextBlock_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        point = e.GetPosition(grid);
        e.MouseDevice.Capture(textBlock);
    }

    private void TextBlock_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        e.TouchDevice.Capture(null);
    }

    private void TextBlock_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.MouseDevice.Capture(null);
    }

    private void Can_PreviewTouchMove(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource is TextBlock)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(grid, e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position.X - point.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(grid, e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position.Y - point.Y);
        }
    }

    private void Can_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource is TextBlock && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && e.StylusDevice == null)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(grid, e.GetPosition(this).X - point.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(grid, e.GetPosition(this).Y - point.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is helpful.